# Android SQlite Leak Problem with CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` that displays data from an sqlite database. I extended `CursorAdapter` to do this. The following code in my `ListActivity` has one big problem: it hands off the cursor to the `CursorAdapter`

```
private boolean refreshListView() {
    final boolean result;
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
    sqliteHelper.open();
    final Cursor cursor = sqliteHelper.fetchAll();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
       //handling some stuff
    } else {
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        final MyCursorAdapter measures = new MyCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
        setListAdapter(measures);
        result = true;
    }        
    return result;
}
```

I noticed that this code leads to frequent `IllegalStateExceptions` "SQLiteDatabase created and never closed".

I tried to fix this by closing the database connection. But if I close it from this method I get `SQLiteMisuseException` which I am guessing is caused by the Adapter still being at work and the cursor is still needed?

I also tried closing the database from `onPause()`. This does not fix the leakage however.

I don't want an app that produces any kind of memory or other leak. But I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have not found any call back or lifecycle methods in either `ListActivity` or `CursorAdapter` that gave me a hint how I should be handling this.

I'd be grateful for any hint on how to fix this. I am starting to suspect that the entire construct is just wrong. I can post more code if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call `sqliteHelper.open()` in `onCreate()` and `sqliteHelper.close()` in `onDestroy()`.

[Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) explains the lifecycle in detail.

Comment: Thanks, at first it didn't seem to work but then it turned out I had made the same mistake in another class. I have no idea why I never tried onDestroy(). I always assumed onPause() would be the best place, teaches me to read instead of going about assuming stuff.