# Cursor is not close, How can I solve it?

Tags: android, cursor, chat

my app runs fine in the ADT emulator but the problem is when I run my app in a real devie. It throws this error.

```
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824): PossibleCursorLeak:content://com.mychat/account,QueryCounter:6
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:399)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at com.example.mychat2.net.AccountsAdapter.update(AccountsAdapter.java:64)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at com.example.mychat2.net.activity.account.Accounts.update(Accounts.java:232)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at com.example.mychat2.net.activity.account.Accounts.onResume(Accounts.java:91)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1190)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5200)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2935)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-21 14:27:10.339: E/CursorLeakDetecter(17824):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code

```
public void update() {
        clear();

        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(ChatPU.ACCOUNT_URI, null, null, null, AccountDbHelper._ID);


        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountDbHelper._ID));
                String jid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountDbHelper.IDS));
                String enabled = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountDbHelper.ENABLED));

                Account account = new Account(id, jid);
                account.setEnabled(enabled.equals("1"));
                add(account);

        while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();

        }

    }
```

I actually read that this error is because I need close my database or my cursor.. but I did it
   cursor.close();
This problem only comes when I test my app in a real device... so anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling close on the cursor after the while loop.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext());
            //other code if needed here

        } 
cursor.close();
```

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), cursor.Close()
closes the cursor, releasing all of its resources and **making it completely invalid**. So, you should close only once.

Also, it is recommended you close the cursor in `onDestroy`

[Android SQlite Leak Problem with CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225374/android-sqlite-leak-problem-with-cursoradapter)

Comment: Well after a week to impplement all to comes in my mind and use you're example, I have to say that it does'nt works for me when I run my app in a real device. On this way I don't have errors, but it say **"hideInsertionPointCursorController, mInsertionPointCursorController is null."**  in yellow color and **"Flag is not 10"** in blue color. This only happends when I run it in a real phone but it fixed when I debug  my app in the same phone.